# 14:04: Usergroup / file permissions problems daemon proces

Tags: permissions, user-management

I'm trying to understand the file permissions in ubuntu, but after reading some material, I still don't understand why the following situation doesn't work:

I have a folder \myfolder\torrents\complete

The permissions on that specific folder:

- Owner: someuser: Read,Write,Execute
- Group: debian-transmission: Read,Write,Execute
- Other : -

The folders myfolder and torrents have the permissions:

- Owner : someuser: Read,Write,Execute
- Group : someuser: Read,Write,Execute
- Other : -

The transmission client is running under the user group debian-transmission. But it's still complaning about not having permissions to access the folder \ myfolder\torrents\complete.

What am I missing here?

BHD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the execute permission to `others` on the folders above `complete`. Without the `execute` permission on a folder, it cannot be traversed:

```
chmod o+x \myfolder \myfolder\torrents
```

Without this, a process running as `debian-transmission` is never able to get past `\myfolder`, let alone `\myfolder\torrents`.

See this [Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) for a discussion.

Unless you run this command recursively (with `-R`, which you shouldn't) this does not give execute permission to files (or anything else) within these directories. Only these two directories are affected.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it for me. Still find not a pleasant idea that everyone is able to execute scripts in those folders.

Comment: @BlackHawkDesign root, no! Did you run it as `chmod -R`?

Comment: I just gave the folder \myfolder and \torrents execute rights to others. Didn't do that recursive, because my folder contains other folders which I don't want anyone else that myuser has access to :) So I didn't do it recursive on root :)

Thanks a lot for the help :) Really appreciated!

Comment: @BlackHawkDesign, good, so no scripts should be executable within it to others.

Comment: Yeah, the only user which should have access to those folders is me. Only the transmission client should have access to that subfolder. The rest runs under my username. Thanks for the double check ;)